# Recieving an AJAX CALL ERROR upon page load

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, wordpress

Bear with me as this is my first question here.  I will try to format it as best I can.

I have installed a contact form plugin to my wordpress site and after setting everything up, I am now getting an error when I load the page that states this:

AJAX CALL ERROR
Error: 0 error
Verify the attribute action of the form. It seems there is an error

I spoke with the developer and he is able to load it on his demo site, I ran the site in debug mode, and looked at the .htaccess information.  He is telling me that there must be something wrong with the server configuration since it only shows on the front end.  I don't see anything in the htaccess file which would cause this.  I am not very familiar with Ajax or htaccess(a little but not much) so That is why I'm asking this here.  Does anyone have a suggestion, because I'm at a loss right now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open up Chrome, go to "Tools" then "Developer Tools", then click on the "Network" tab, try to load the page and monitor the AJAX calls the form is making. You can click on them and look at the request and response headers and the content returned by all the AJAX calls. Find the one that is broken. Start your debugging there.

If the server is returning some sort of error, like a 500 error, then look at the contents of the page being returned, there may be a better error message there. If it's a 404 error, then you're form is trying to make an AJAX call to something the server can't find.